# Difference between objectivity and isotropy

Tags: continuum-mechanics

For a material property to be objective (frame-indifferent) it should not change if another observer is measuring it from his own reference frame.

For a material property to be isotropic means that it is the same in all directions.

But doesn't that make isotropy and objectivity the same? Since changing observer looks like passive transformation whereas rotating and translating the material itself and observing the properties again looks like active transformation.

If they are the same, then why do we have different conditions for strain energy function in case of material objectivity and material isotropy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you boost to a different velocity, the properties could change but still look the same from all directions. Thus it would be isotropic but not objective. On the other hand, consider a hologram (those laser-etched ones). It shows a different image from each angle, but every observer at those angles would see the same set of images. Objective but not isotropic.

Answer (score 1):

For an elastic material, the stress tensor $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ is some function of the deformation gradient $\mathbf{F}$:

$$\boldsymbol{\sigma} = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{F})$$

**Material objectivity** or **frame indifference condition** implies that:

$$\mathbf{R}^T\boldsymbol{\sigma}\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{R}^T\mathbf{F})$$

For any rotation tranformation $\mathbf{R}\in \text{SO}(3)$. The above invariance implies that the elastic energy has to be of the form:

$$W_e = W(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) = \tilde{W}(\mathbf{F}^T\mathbf{F})$$

where $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$ is the strain tensor you are using as strain measure, and in addition:

$$\boldsymbol{\sigma} = \frac{\partial W}{\partial \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}} = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{F})$$

However, **isotropy** is much more restrictive: elastic energy need invariant under rotations of the strain tensor:

$$W(\mathbf{R}\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) = W(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon})$$

for all $\mathbf{R}\in \text{SO}(3)$. This condition implies that necesarily we have:

$$W_e = W(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) = \hat{W}(I_1(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}), I_2(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}), I_3(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}))$$

where $I_i(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon})$ are algebraic invariants of the strain tensor, for example, we can take:

$$I_1(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) = \text{tr}(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}), \quad I_2(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) = \text{tr}(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}^2), \quad I_3(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) = \text{tr}(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}^3)$$

although the latter choice is not unique.